# Make sure state is updated before rendering data in React Modal

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using Material-UI component, useState hook and NextJS framework.

I am mapping someData in my render, the structure of a someData element is :

```
someData[i] : {
  "id": number,
  "name": string,
  "surname": string
}
```

My problem is to pass mapped data to Modal (specific to the mapped data).

```
{someData.map((data) => (
  <Grid item key={data.id}>
    <Card>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography>
          {data.surname} {data.name}'s card.
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setModalData(data);
          setOpen(true);
        }}
      >
        Follow
      </Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={setOpen(false)}
      >
        <Box>
          <Typography>
            Follow {modalData.surname} ?
          </Typography>
          <Button onClick={() => handleFollowSubmit(modalData)}> 
               /*Function declared not important here*/
            Yes
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </Card>
  </Grid>
))}
```

And the state used here are:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false); // to handle the Modal opening
const [modalData, setModalData] = useState(null); // to pass Data to the modal
```

The idea is that you can't pass mapped data to a modal using the mapping, you have to use a State Hook to do so: When you open a modal, you pass the corresponding data through the State Hook.

But when I render the webpage I get this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'surname')

Pointing at modalData.surname

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is not clear. Can you post the full code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
Initializing modalData like this:

```
const [modalData, setModalData] = useState({"id": number, "name": string, "surname": string})
```

solves the problem. I think initializing it with null created an error as the components are rendered before the data is fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `!!modalData` to its `open` prop?

```
 <Modal
  open={!!modalData && open}
  onClose={setOpen(false)}
/>
```

Comment: It's in the right path! Now the page renders but when I do my query to get someData, the same error appears...

Comment: Maybe you can add a codesandbox, including your query. Can't judge your lifecycle from these snippets.